# Kernel panic Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel

I am getting Kernel panic Ubuntu 20.04 when trying to shutdown. Reboot somehow goes through. Tried shutdown using init 0 or from the GUI yielding same result. image here https://i.redd.it/a2w2rlci1mw41.jpg. How to troubleshoot this error message
sudo lshw -C memory

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Alienware
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0.21
       date: 02/25/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2666C16/16G
          vendor: 00002B0C0000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 11298D68
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2666 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2666C16/16G
          vendor: 00002B0C0000
          physical id: 2
          serial: 0B29EE67
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2666MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 34
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 35
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 36
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 9MiB
       capacity: 9MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec100000-ec103fff
```

Comment: why reboot works and shutdown does not

Comment: Muc more detail is needed. Is it a fresh install or a modifiesd system? What is the hardware? I can't reproduce it, so the question doesn't conatain any information.

Comment: fresh install on dell alienware r7 dual boot. windows is installed on an nvme 256 gb drive. intel i5 8400, 32G ram, 512 GB SSD (the one where ubuntu is installed) nvdia 1050ti asus gpu

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: for FC32 kernel panic is consistent irrespective of shutdown or reboot. with / without nvdia drivers. in ubuntu the reboot works but why not shutdown. how to troubleshoot further. yet to install nvdia drivers on ubuntu

Comment: Pity we can't see the stack trace, and also the full screen. What's the name of the module that ends with `250_dw` on the edge of the screen? Could be connected to it. Could you try unloading it? Also, what is your kernel version?

Comment: Anyway I think the best would be to file a kernel bug. It's unlikely any help will come without actually inspecting (and fixing) the kernel code.

Comment: here is one more pic https://photos.app.goo.gl/2Ln5Hp31XdZjCEMk9

Comment: thanks filed the bug https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207569

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: And @MrinalBhattacharjee please [edit] your question with all relevant information, **don't** use comments.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

**Note**: Backup important files before performing a BIOS update.

You have BIOS 1.0.19, and the latest is 1.0.21, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=p43vg&oscode=wt64a&productcode=alienware-aurora-r7-desktop).

**Memory**

Go [here](https://www.memtest86.com/) and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Nvidia**

Confirm that you have Nvidia driver 440.82 installed. It can be downloaded [here](https://www.geforce.com/drivers).

**SSD**

If your SSD is Samsung, in Windows, download their Samsung Magician software and check your firmware. Download it [here](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/product/consumer/magician/).

Comment: 1. Bios update done
2. Shall perfofm the memtest and will tag you
3. nvdia driver details below
```Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] driver: nvidia v: 440.64 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.64
```
4. SSD is Fujitsu tried installing on a toshiba HDD same result hence ruling it out.

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee It looks like you're a candidate for a newer Nvidia driver. After that, check your shutdown again. Report back. Also... please edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: sudo lshw -C memory

Comment: vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: ```free -h
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       3.4Gi        22Gi       618Mi       5.0Gi        26Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee Your memory config looks fine. vm.swappiness looks fine. Keep an eye on swap to see if you need to bump it up a tad.

Comment: Interesting. I don't recall allocation anything for swap.

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee On fresh installs, a 2G /swapfile is automatically created. All systems need swap.

Comment: I thought with 32gigs of memory I would not need it

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee ALL systems need swap. With 32G RAM, it probably won't need to be bigger than 4G. You'll just need to keep an eye on swap usage.

Comment: @MrinalBhattacharjee Status please...

Comment: Still the same. Updated to proprietary nvdia latest drivers. Might try out blocking the kernel module i2c_designware core.